# I need a good description of a flow control valve for a tankless gas geysers. Preferably the battery type

Tags: mechanisms, mechanical

I need to understand the working of the flow control valve of a battery operated tankless gas water heater.
It's the two or three knob geyser that uses 2 x D-cell batteries for ignition.
But I struggle to find any detailed description of it.
I want to know how all the parts interact.
Does anybody know of the existence of such a tutorial?
An animated video perhaps?